# Python: How to combine two columns of text with different font styles retained

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to combine two columns in Excel using python, but the two columns of data have different font sizes and colors. Is it possible to merge two columns of text with different font styles retained?

Here is an example:

[image: example.]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is the documentation in pandas related with styling based on conditions:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.1/user_guide/style.html